# bound for some complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

Let $f(z)=\frac{\cosh(\alpha z)}{\cosh(\beta z)}$, $g(z)=\frac{z\sinh(\alpha z)-\gamma\cosh(\alpha z)}{z\sinh(\beta z)+\gamma\cosh(\beta z)}$, where $\alpha, \beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha>0, \beta>0,\gamma>0$ and $\alpha<\beta$. The domain for both the function is first quadrant, i.e., $\{z: \Re(z)>0, \Im(z)>0\}$. I have to show that $\vert f(z)\vert<1$ and $\vert g(z)\vert<1$.

My observation: If I take $z$ with $\Im(z)=0$, i.e., the real valued $f,g$ satisfy the claim. I have also tried to show $1-\vert f(z)\vert^2 >0$ or $1-\vert g(z)\vert^2 >0$, but failed. I numerically check that the claims are true.

Any helps or hints?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not look at $g$ but the claim for $f$ is false: the function $\alpha\mapsto|\cosh(\alpha z)|$ [is not monotone](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Ccosh%28x%280.1%2Bi%5Cpi%2F4%29%29%7C) for $z=0.1+i\pi/4.$

Comment: look at the boundary - $z=iy, y>0$ then $f(iy)=\cos (\alpha y)/\cos (\beta y)$ and is obviously not bounded by $1$ in general so there will be points in the first quadrant where $f
>1$; see what happens for $g(iy)$; by maximum modulus you need that $f,g$ remain bounded by $1$ on the boundary, so you always check there first